# How to tell if video has audio?

Tags: php, audio, video, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I'm using FFmpeg-php to convert videos. When I want to convert a video that has no audio, it gives me an error on these lines:

```
$srcAB = $ffmpegObj->getAudioBitRate();
$srcAR = $ffmpegObj->getAudioSampleRate();
```

Is there a way within ffmpeg-php to know if a video has any audio, so I can skip the above lines above and give both `$srcAB` and `$srcAR` a value of 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know a lot about FFMpeg, but a quick search gives me [the API](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/doc/api/ffmpeg_movie.php).

Looks like there are methods for checking audio, see `$movie->hasAudio()`. Returns true if an audio stream is present.

So then you'd be looking at something like `if(ffmpegObj->hasAudio()){ //do something };`